# Create multidimensional list in python through two other lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to create a new one.

For instance

```
a = ["Street zero", "Street one", "Street two"]
b = [0,1,2]

newlist [0][0] = "Street zero"
newlist [1][1] = "Street one"
newlist [2][2] = "Street two"
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: What about the other elements in your two-dimensional array (e.g. newlist[0][1])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean `enumerate`?

```
>>> list(enumerate(a))
[(0, 'Street zero'), (1, 'Street one'), (2, 'Street two')]
```

Or `zip`:

```
>>> zip(b, a)
[(0, 'Street zero'), (1, 'Street one'), (2, 'Street two')]
```

(that uses items from `b` as indexes)

Comment: not really, I want more like that, but I need to use another list as integers